# How can I pass the row id from a table with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a table I want to add a button to each row and edit the row in a form. I need to pass the LineNumber into my getjson request. how can I do that? Here is my table and my getjson. (edit)I just noticed I'm asking for LineNumber but what I really want is the id of the button pushed '+value.linenumber+'.

```
//table goes though a loop.
table_obj.append($('<tr><td>'+value.SLN+'</td><td  >'+value.Type+'</td><td     >
'+value.StopNumber+'</td><td>'+value.LoName+'</td><td >'+value.ReferenceNo+'</td>
<td class="hide" >'+value.TypeId+'</td><td class="hide" >'+value.LocationId+'</td>
<td class="hide" >'+value.lineNumber+'</td><td><button id='+value.lineNumber+'
onclick=edit()>Edit</button></td></tr>'));

//getjson
<script> function edit()
$.getJSON("editstops.php",{ LineNumber:$('#LineNumber').val() },stophandler)
var stophandler = function(data){
$("#SLNS").val(data[0].value.LoadNumber);
$("#Type").val(data[0].value.Type);
    $("#StopNumber").val(data[0].value.StopNumber);
$("#LoName").val(data[0].value.LoName);
$("#ReferenceNo").val(data[0].value.ReferenceNo);   
$("#TypeId").val(data[0].value.TypeId);
$("#LocationId").val(data[0].value.LocationId);
    $("#LineNumber").val(data[0].value.Linenumber);
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button tag, you already have the line number specified as the ID attribute. You can just as easily pass it into the `edit()` function as an argument:

```
<button id='+value.lineNumber+' onclick="edit('+value.lineNumber+')">Edit</button></td></tr>
```

Then your edit function can accept this argument and use it:

```
function edit(lineNumber) {
    $.getJSON("editstops.php",{ LineNumber: lineNumber }, stophandler);
}
```

Note that if your buttons are inside a `form` tag you might also need to add a `return false;` after calling `edit()` to prevent it from submitting the form and refreshing the page.

Simple working example: http://jsbin.com/okesom/2/edit

Alternatively you could leave off the `onclick` event in your button tag entirely. After your loop is done and the table is built, attach an event to all the buttons like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var lineNumber = $(this).attr('id');
    $.getJSON("editstops.php",{ LineNumber: lineNumber }, stophandler);
});
```

Here is a quick example of the second option: http://jsbin.com/ibokon/2/edit

Comment: I went with the first opption since I was pretty much there but when I ckick the button the whole page reloads and that wipes out the request.

Comment: @CraigKuyper I updated option 1 with an example link. It's passing in the line number to the edit() function, and the page is not refreshing. Something else must be going on. Maybe you could setup a jsbin example of your own that shows the problem? I'd be happy to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Oh! You probably have a <form> tag around your buttons, and the buttons are submitting the form. I just updated my answer and example link. Add a "return false;" after calling edit(). Though at this point I would think option #2 is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Yes the table is inside <form> tags. That fixed it Thank you. I also had to fix editstops.php I was asking for $_GET['lineNumber'] instead of $_GET['LineNumber'] .